# LESS :extend generates incorrect CSS

Tags: css, less, extend

I'm working on a Rails application with Bootstrap, and I'm using semantic class names in my HTML. This means I'm using `extend` a lot. However, LESS generates some incorrect CSS. I'm not sure if it's a bug or if I'm doing something wrong.

Here's some LESS code to reproduce the issue:

```
@import "bootstrap";

body#home input {
   &:extend(.form-control all);
}
```

My `input` is styled correctly, but the additional following CSS is generated:

```
textarea.form-control,
textareabody#home input {
  height: auto;
}

.form-inline body#home input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I understand that this happens because `extend` is just syntactic sugar for search and replace, but isn't there any workaround for the issue?

Comment: If you use *exact* matches for `:extend` (without the `all` keyword) that shouldn't happen.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, ```.form-control``` is used in so many different forms that I'm probably better off adding a couple of classes to my inputs.

Comment: That's just how it is defined in [`forms.less`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.2.0/less/forms.less#L150). Solution: don't use excessive selectors like `body#home`, it's no way better then `#body-home`, `.body-home` or even just `#home` (you don't set the same id to different elements, do you?).

Comment: Using just ```#home``` won't solve the issue, although I'll do it. I would still get something like ```textarea#home input```, which is not what I want.

Comment: Which means you want something that Bootstrap CSS classes were not designed for (officially they are not meant to be reused at all, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113419/extending-bootstrap-3-less-btn-group-not-working/24125264#comment37200018_24113419 and other comments linked there).

Comment: Got it. So the smarter solution is to add the classes directly to my HTML, right? (I'm not sarcastic, actually asking!)

Comment: In context of Bootstrap, yes, its classes are designed to be used in HTML only (regardless of whatever pros/cons the non-semantic approach has). This of course does not mean you can't try to reuse some of those components, just that the results may be strange/unpredictable (and the desired stuff finally to be not reachable "the easy way" at all).

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that most Bootstrap sites (including Linode's) use the classes directly in their HTML, so I've decided to use the same approach as well. Thanks!