# Less inheritance fails with "undefined class"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1 and adding my own LESS styles with semantic names.

Using `grunt-customize-bootstrap` I've added `mystyles.less` at the end of `bootstrap.less`, just before the inclusion of `responsive-utilities.less` (I don't know why, that's `grunt-customize-bootstrap`'s default behavior, but even in the last position the issue remains).

I defined my own dropdown menu like this:

```
.my-dropdown {
  .dropdown;
  > .my-toggle {
    .dropdown-toggle;
  }
}
```

This is how it is defined in bootstrap's `panels.less`:

```
> .dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
  color: inherit;
}
```

But grunt is not really happy about it:

```
Running "less:compile" (less) task
>> NameError: .dropdown-toggle is undefined in less/mystyles.less on line 51, column 15:
>> 50             > .my-toggle {
>> 51               .dropdown-toggle;
>> 52             }
Warning: Error compiling less/bootstrap.less Use --force to continue.
```

I've observed this behavior with other classes, for example `.navbar-right` (while for example `.pull-right()` is ok), but I can't really understand what I'm doing wrong. Can anybody illuminate me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `.dropdown-toggle` is defined there inside `.panel-heading` class as part of the `.dropdown .dropdown-toggle` selector, it is not available as a standalone global scope mixin (like you try to invoke it). The `.panel-heading` and `.dropdown` classes work like [namespaces](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-namespaces-amp-accessors) in this case so to access `.dropdown-toggle` there you need to specify "complete path" to it, e.g.:

```
.my-toggle {
    .panel-heading > .dropdown > .dropdown-toggle;
    // or just:
    .panel-heading.dropdown.dropdown-toggle;
    // if you prefer shorter things
}
```

**However** this won't work the way you probably expect it to. Note that the `.dropdown-toggle` class is defined not only once inside `.panel-heading` but also several (~10) times inside other classes (e.g. `.btn-group`, `.input-group-btn` etc.). So if you need to get other `.dropdown-toggle` styles you also need to invoke these other `.dropdown-toggle` definitions.

Most likely [`extend`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) will serve in this particular case better but it also has its limitations. Usually I imply that an approach to try to use Bootstrap as a CSS construction kit for your own semantic classes is a dead end. Some things are possible (using mixins, extend, [referencing](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference) "bootstrap.css" and all of this all together) but many are just not (or at least are super-bloating both in coding (time) and in final CSS result). See my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840711/bootstrap-3-with-less-how-to-handle-bootstraps-nested-rules#comment36791109_23840711), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983475/a-smarter-way-for-integrating-bootstrapor-even-from-another-less-css-file-clas#comment35124805_22983475) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113419/extending-bootstrap-3-less-btn-group-not-working/24125264#comment37200018_24113419) for more details on this.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but thanks anyway for the load of info :)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. Nor `>` neither whitespace have any meaning for the namespaced mixins, so even if mixin calls pretend to look like HTML selector pattern matching they actually are not (so `.panel-heading > .dropdown > .dropdown-toggle`; and `.panel-heading.dropdown.dropdown-toggle;` are equivalent in this case. And that's another big story why it is so).

Comment: Thanks again for the great lesson, and sorry for the mistaken edit.