# Bootstrap's control-label not recognised LESS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I am using Twitter's bootstrap LESS in a project and I am trying to setup a form but I can't seem to use `.control-label;` on my label. This is my code:

`label {
    .control-label;
}`

I have read somewhere I should use the namespace `.form-horizontal > .control-label;` but that doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What you have should work. Are you sure you have included the file that `.control-label` is defined in? Which is forms.less I believe. How are you compiling your LESS?

Comment: I have included bootstrap.less that file includes forms.less but to make sure i have all so included forms.less. Sadly that didn't work :(

Comment: oh and LESS is compiled by a VS2013 plugin called webessentials.

Comment: As @seven-phases-max has pointed out below your issue has to do with scope. `.control-label` is defined inside of `.form-inline` of the forms.less file. Attempting to call/use `.control-label` outside of the `.form-inline` definition won't work as it only exists inside of `.form-inline`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.control-label:extend(.label) {
  additional props
}
```

Comment: hope that is what you are looking for :)

Comment: That doesn't work, the `label` should get the same properties as the .control-label class.

Comment: ah alright got it
just a moment just have to check for less. I'm used to sass

Comment: @Axel the OP should be able to use the CSS class as a Mixin as they posted in their question. I'm thinking there is an issue with the OP's setup.

Comment: @hungerstar Only if the class is actually defined in a scope visible at the point you try to invoke it. `.control-label` [*is not*](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.2.0/less/forms.less#L431) in fact, so OP's result is expected. See also very similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240134.

Comment: A yes, scope. My apologies for overlooking that.