# How to combine several Font Awesome classes into one selector using LESS?

Tags: css, less, font-awesome

I'm trying to nest a bunch of font awesome styles into a single css class I can use whenever I'd like. However, I'm getting an error with "Undeclared Mixin".

My .less file looks something like this:

```
@import (reference) "../Content/bootstrap/font-awesome/font-awesome.less";

.step-current {
    .fa;
    .fa-play;
    .text-success;
}
```

In this case all I'd like to do is apply the styles .fa, .fa-play, and .text-success whenever I use the class step-current on an element. However, I'm getting an error when I try to compile this less file (using Web Compiler 2015).

.fa-play is an Undeclare Mixin.

Obviously I could just go like this: class="fa fa-play text-success" within my tag but I'd really like to know if it's possible to do the above.

Thanks

Comment: @dippas thanks for unflagging this. I had upvoted the comment that said it might be a duplicate, but then looked a little further and realized it wasn't. You were so on-the-ball that it was marked as a duplicate before I undid my vote - can't fault you for being speedy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LESS is tripping up because Font Awesome doesn't style `.fa-play`, only `.fa-play:before`. Get around this by using [LESS's `:extend` syntax](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) (see also this [css-tricks write-up/tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/reference-imports-in-less-are-kinda-cool/)). The key is the [`all` keyword](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-all-), which will bring in the `:before` styles.

```
.custom-class {
    &:extend(.fa, .fa-play all);
    .text-success
}
```

(Just guessing about what to do with your `.text-success` - that doesn't appear to be part of Font Awesome… but then it wasn't part of your problem, so I guess it doesn't matter. You might need to use `:extend` to pull it in, or you might be able to just use it as a normal old LESS mixin as I did above.)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!