# custom btn-group class on td with less

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I want to be able to use a td as a btn-group, with a custom class but cant get it to work correctly

#### Markup

```
<td class="actions">
    <a href="/foo/bar" class="btn"><span class="fa fa-edit fa-lg "></span> Edit</a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"><span class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg "></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/foo/bar"><span class="fa fa-times fa-lg "></span> Delete</a></li>
        <li><a href="/foo/bar"><span class="fa fa-times fa-lg "></span> Delete</a></li>
        <li><a href="/foo/bar"><span class="fa fa-times fa-lg "></span> Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

#### Less

```
td {
    &.actions {
        > a {
            .pull-left;
            .button-size(@padding-xs-vertical; @padding-xs-horizontal; @font-size-small; @line-height-small; @border-radius-small);
            &:first-child {
                .button-variant(@btn-default-color; @btn-default-bg; @btn-default-border);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a couple things such as `&.actions:extend(:btn-group)`

but the toggle does not show the `UL` and it does not create a button group (eg: the buttons have rounded corners all the way round)

Adding the `btn-group` class to the td and everything works fine.

Comment: I guess it should be `extend(.btn-group all)` (note that this will generate quite bloating CSS though). See also related stuff: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23840711),
[2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22983475),
[3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24113419),
[4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24240134).

Comment: Have tried `extend(.btn-group all)` with no change vs `extend(.btn-group)`

Comment: I can't imagine why it would not work. Well, `extend(.btn-group all)` is the correct method in this case, see `extend` docs and `.btn-group` definitions. Check the compiled CSS - if you did everything correctly `td.actions` should appear there everywhere `.btn-group` is (and if it's not double check the syntax you used). Also there's a [#2206 bug](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2206) (it will apply if you have your `td` nested wthin another ruleset) so instead of `&.actions:extend(.btn-group all)` it's more safe to put `&:extend(.btn-group all);` into the `.actions` ruleset.

Comment: Looks like it was the bug you mentioned, converted to use `&:extend(.btn-group all)` and it seems to work fine. Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assembling an answer from comments above.
In this case [`extend all`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-all-) should be used since `.btn-group` is not just some single "flat" style but a set of selectors/rulesets with quite complex nesting hierarchy, so:

```
td {
    &.actions:extend(.btn-group all) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Although because of the [#2206 bug](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2206) it might be more safe to write it as:

```
td {
    &.actions {
        &:extend(.btn-group all);
        // ...
    }
}
```